# How to count appearances of primary key values in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Probably an easy question but it got me stuck:

If I have three tables:

table for magazines:

Magazine(**title, publisher**, topic)

the customers:

Customer(**cid**, name)

and the subscriptions for the magazines by customers:

Subscriptions(**cid, title, publisher**, start_date)

as you can see, the primary key of magazine table has two attributes, so how to write a query that will count the number of subscriptions of each customer for magazines?

I tried:

```
select cid, count(distinct title)
from subscriptions
group by cid
```

but it counts the number of titles of magazines for each customer and not the combination of title with publisher which is the primary key of magazines (two different magazines can have same title but different publishers).

Comment: Is the primary key for Subscribers `cid`, `title` and `publisher`? If so, the count will surely always be 1 per customer per  title and publisher combination.

Comment: Your query will produce the number of rows that each cid has, regardless of how the subscriptions are organized.  Whether magazines use title and publisher as the primary key or not is not relevant--unless there is something you have not made clear in your question.  The key to magazine is only important if you need the magazine topic.

Comment: What are you trying to count?

Comment: I am trying to count number of different magazines each customer is subscribed to but to count the titles of magazines is not enough because two different magazines can have same title but different publishers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
select cid, count(distinct (title || publisher))
  from subscribes group by cid;
```

Provided `||` is the string concatenation operator.

Comment: Note that 'abc' || 'def' is the same as 'abcd' || 'ef'.

Comment: You could concat another character between the two that shouldn't show up in magazine titles or publisher names - for example `CONCAT(title, '\`', publisher)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `(cid, title, publisher)` is in fact a `PRIMARY KEY` or otherwise `UNIQUE`, you can use `COUNT(*)` to count all rows in each group:

```
SELECT cid, COUNT(*) AS num_zines
FROM Subscriptions
GROUP BY cid
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to formulate a query to solve the problem, you should think about your data model. You are storing the titles and publishers twice which leads to redundancy. It would be better to add an artificial key *mid* to **magazine** and to use this key in the relation table **subscription**, resulting to this:

```
magazine (mid, title, publisher, topic);
customer (cid, name);
subscription (cid, mid, start_date);
```

And now the resulting query is easy as this:

```
SELECT cid, count(mid)
FROM subscription
GROUP BY cid
```